# Setting localStorage to a variable | What happens?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below.

Is all of local storage pulled from the disk into the variable cache?

```
(function(){
    var publik = {}, 
        cache = localStorage;

    publik.get = function(){};  // getter
    publik.set = function(){};  // setter
    return publik;
})()
```

Yes/No and Why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are storing in a variable is a pointer to the localStorage object, this object does not "contains" the disk data, it gives it to you when you ask for it.

So no, it does not pull the disk data into memory

Update:

If you want to cache the local storage you can interate it and ask for every key one by one

```
for (var key in localStorage)
    cache[key] = localStorage[key];
```

Here you ASK the local storage for every key and it reads it.

Comment: O.K.  How do I cache it then?

Comment: you can ask local storage for every key and cache them one by one

    for (var i in localStorage)
        cache[i] = localStorage[i];

Comment: Why would you desire to make a clone of the localStorage? Maybe that way we can come up with a better solution. What you suggest requires cloning it (iterate and copy)

Comment: Well, a better solution is to save only one key on localStorage and there store as many keys as you want, this way you only have to retrieve one key

Comment: I was told that hitting the disk( local storage is on disk or flash ) is slower then hitting the RAM...

Comment: It is, it should be used to store data while the user closes your page and opens it again. While your page is running you must use variables who are stored on the RAM

Answer (score 1):

No.

cache now references the localStorage object. This object references it's properties too. You're not doing a "clone" of the object, but simply telling cache to reference it.